# HttpAntiForgeryException error in Sitecore form

Tags: sitecore-forms

We are getting the below error in `Sitecore Forms` on `Production` site.
[image]

We are using `Sitecore 9.1.1` version with `SXA`.

I went through many articles/blogs but could not find anything relevant
Please suggest.

Comment: Did you check this article related to the caching? https://madhuanbalagan.com/sitecore-9-forms-the-required-anti-forgery-cookie-requestverificationtoken-is-not-present

Comment: I have already checked this link and we are not using cache in our site.

Comment: Did you verify whether anti forgery token is generated by inspecting the form in browser Dev tools. If yes, is token is changing on every refresh? If token itself is not generated, then you have to check the Form.cshtml. @Html.AntiForgeryToken() line should be presented.

Comment: I have checked all the details and found that token is changing after refreshing the page. Is it possible to get this error after getting 500 error?

Comment: Are you getting 500 error. Did you check event viewer for further details?

Answer (score 1):

If the web.config file has the correct settings for the AntiForgery token, then you should verify that the ValidateAntiForgeryToken attribute is present in the controller responsible for form submission. Additionally, you should ensure that @Html.AntiForgeryToken() is present in the form view.

Answer (score 1):

I have disabled the field caching section for rendering items associated with the page. Despite this, I encountered the same issue. Upon further investigation, I discovered that disabling the following three fields resolved the issue:

- Cacheable [shared]
- Clear on Index Update [shared]
- Vary By Data [shared]

Answer (score 0):

The way Anti-Forgery works in Sitecore is the following:

1. There should be `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` HTML helper in the form razor view
2. A validation should be made in the forms controller using the `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` action filter

If you have these then an HTML code should be generated like below:

```
<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="xxxx">
```

Although the blog is about implementing forms in JSS, the concept could be understood from this link: [Sitecore JSS Anti-forgery](https://www.coreysmith.co/sitecore-jss-anti-forgery-tokens/)